# How to prevent routes from being called multiple time in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am new to node.js and I am trying to make a simple task list app using express.js and express-session. However, for a reason that I don't understand most of the routes are called two or tree times when I make a request and it shouldn't. For instance, if I send a request to `/new` the new task is sometimes added two (or three) times instead of one and this causes a problem...

I read in other threads that the problem could come from the browser trying to get a favicon, however if I log all incoming request url (`console.log(req.url)`) on the `/new` route, the duplicated requests are always `/new` and not a favicon...

Here is my code :

```js
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');

// Create a new express application instance
var app = express();

// Initialize session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {}
}));

// Initialize req.session.tasks if needed
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.tasks === undefined) {
        req.session.tasks = [];
    }
    next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.session.tasks);
});

// Create a Test Task 
app.get('/new', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
    req.session.tasks.push("Test Task");
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/clear', function (req, res) {
    req.session.tasks = [];
    res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Task Server is listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Do you have a idea of what could be the cause of this problem and how to avoid it ??

Thanks a lot !

Comment: how do you make your get request?

Comment: I am simply using a browser for the moment (safari) on http://localhost:3000/new .. could it be a problem with safari?

Comment: Try to `console.log(req.session.tasks)` after `tasks.push` and see the output after a get request. Is   `console.log(req.session.tasks)` called once or more times?

Comment: It is called two times. Heres the output after the request : `Task Server is listening on port 3000!
[ 'Test Task' ]
[ 'Test Task', 'Test Task' ]`